# При логирогованни в google Api произошла ошибка:

Tags: laravel

Laravel \ Socialite \ Two \ InvalidStateException 
No message

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider){
$user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
return $user->token;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить следующий код

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider){
$user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
return $user->token;

}
```